# Why IEEE802.11w doesn't protect public action frames?

Tags: wifi

currently I am working on 802.11 protocols. I find that in 802.11w Public Action Frame is not robust. Suprisingly, in [TGw reports](http://www.ieee802.org/11/Reports/tgw_update.htm) I saw a discussion on this topic. Therefore, why they decided not to protect Public Action Frames?